# Zip files being open as files by APACHE server instead of downloading

Tags: apache, .htaccess, download

The error that I get is from PHP because APACHE is tryng to pass the .zip file through the PHP interpreter.

But this post is not regarding any PHP script, or setting up headers from PHP to make the file download. It is about preventing APACHE from passing the file through PHP and generate a download instead.

I have found a few answers that involve adding File Exceptions on the .htaccess but still without success and I get the follwing Parse error message:

```
Parse error: in /home/user/public_html/downloads/files/1/test-file-132110.zip on line 431
```

Comment: "involve adding File Exceptions on the .htaccess" - What do you mean by that exactly? "APACHE not trying to read and execute the file" - do you mean passing the `.zip` file through the PHP(?) interpreter? This depends on how PHP has been installed on the server and would seem to be an error in the server config. Do you have access to the server config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the .htaccess instructions that I found that work:

```
<Location "/downloads/files/">
    <Files *.*>
        ForceType application/octet-stream
        Header set Content-Disposition attachment
    </Files>
</Location>
```

The previous example is not so great because I want to chose specific extensions, lile doc, zip, etc. So I tried these instead:

```
<Location "/downloads/files/">
  <FilesMatch ".(?i:doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|zip|rar)$">
     ForceType application/octet-stream
     Header set Content-Disposition attachment
  </FilesMatch>
</Location>
```

or this, without specifying a location:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|zip|rar)$">
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: The `<Location>` directive is not valid in `.htaccess` and "should" result in a 500 Internal Server Error on Apache. (?) If the question is not about "setting up headers to make the file download" then you don't need the `header` directive? That simply sets an HTTP response header that is sent back to the client and has nothing to do with the server seemingly erroneously parsing files as PHP?